# How to solve filtered API results in Vue app returning undefined?

Tags: api, vue.js, vue-cli

As a newbie I’m trying to get my head around Vue and I’m having difficulty with the functionality of my Github jobs api app. The full project can be viewed here https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-banach-u6fzg

I’m having issues with the filtering of the api results, in particular the ‘load more’ button which, ideally, will filter the results of the api into batches of 10. The issues are:

- The load more function works initially, but once there are, say, 30 results displayed on the app, the search function at the top does not work.
- The search function works on the initial render of the page with 10 results being displayed, but the ‘load more’ button/function does not work on the returned results. As an example, if you search for ‘UK’ in location you get an initial 10 results, but a console.log reveals that there are 50 results returned from the api, which come back as undefined so are not displayed.
  I’m not sure if these two problems are linked to a single issue.

Any advice would be much appreciated, as well as any feedback on how I’ve implemented the app.

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use computed prop instead of a function and you also you should reset loaded items counter if `jobs` loaded again.
See [modified code](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-banzai-6til0?file=/src/components/Jobs.vue)

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="jobs.length">
    <div v-for="job in filterJobs" v-bind:key="job.id">
      <!-- <div v-for="job in jobs" v-bind:key="job.id"> -->
      <Job v-bind:job="job" />
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="loadMore">Load More</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Job from "./Job";
export default {
  name: "Jobs",
  components: {
    Job,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      jobCount: 10,
    };
  },
  props: ["jobs"],
  watch: {
    // watcher to reset a counter
    jobs(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.jobCount = 10;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    // computed prop instead of function, that way it would be reactive
    filterJobs() {
      return this.jobs.slice(0, this.jobCount);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    loadMore() {
      // we need to check if we are exceeding a length of jobs array or not
      if (this.jobCount + 10 <= this.jobs.length) {
        this.jobCount += 10;
      } else {
        this.jobCount = this.jobs.length;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="stylus" scoped></style>
```

Comment: Brilliant - that has done the trick! Could you please elaborate why we use computed instead of methods for the filterJobs function? Is it because the function would need to be continuously called in the methods for it to react to the updated search data, whereas computed can keep track of it automatically? Is that why it wasn't working previously as the function was only being called on the initial render?

Comment: A function is not reactive and yes that's why it's not called when `jobs` is changed.